# 2D array of strings, where first index is row and second word

Tags: arrays, struct, 2d

I ask for help. I need to create 2D array of strings and store in there whole text file (.txt). The first index of array has to be row and the second index has to be word. I already store the words into *slova[40]. '*buff' is one row in text file. After that I need to pass the 2D array to another function where I create struct, which will contain information about every row (how many words row have).

```cpp
    void zapis_pole (char *buff,int radek){
    char pole[40][20];
    int i=0,k=0,slovo=0;
    char *slova[40];
    
    //rozdelovani slov podle tecek, carek, otazniku, prazdnych mist atd..
    while(buff[i]!='\0'){
        if(buff[i]==' '|| buff[i]=='\n' || buff[i]==',' || buff[i]=='.' || buff[i]=='?' || buff[i]=='\0'){
            if(buff[i+1]!=' ' && buff[i+1]!= '\0' && buff[i+1]!= '?' && buff[i+1]!= '.'){
            pole[slovo][k++]='\0';
            slovo++;
            k=0;    
            }
        }else { 
            pole[slovo][k++]=buff[i];           
        }           
        i++;
    }
    
    for(i=0;i<=slovo;i++){
    slova[i]= (char*) malloc( 32 * sizeof( char ) );
    strcpy(slova[i], pole[i] );
    naplneni_pomocneho_pole(radek,slova[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should first correct the errors in the function you have before starting with the next one. `valgrind` can help you.

Comment: How shall the `struct` be structured?